# Does MAC OS have anything like _wenviron?

Tags: c++, macos

What I am trying to do is to make a table of all environment variables that exist in the system. My solution works in windows and works for char environment variables (using environ) but doesn't work on Mac.

This is the solution that I have at the moment:

```
template<>
char** GetEnviron(void)
{
    return environ;
}

template<>
wchar_t** GetEnviron(void)
{
    return _wenviron;
}

T* pEnvVarPair = *GetEnviron<T*>();
for (int idx = 1; pEnvVarPair; idx++)
{
    ...
    pEnvVarPair = *(GetEnviron<T*>() + idx);
};
```

In stdlib.h there is the following declaration:

```
#define _wenviron (*__p__wenviron()) // Pointer to wide environment table
```

which is under ifdef #ifdef _CRT_USE_WINAPI_FAMILY_DESKTOP_APP

Does Mac have something similar?

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I think OP was looking for an equivalent to `extern wchar_t **_wenviron;` (note the type) I don't think there is such a thing on macOS.

Comment: @rustyx NO this is not a duplicate because this is about wchat_t variables specifically which existing question doesn't touch. Please undo your closing the question

Comment: Ok I see. No there is no wenviron on POSIX systems. But `environ` should be properly encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: @rustyx I see... Thanks!

Comment: Are you aware that the 3rd parameter to main is an array of env vars?

Comment: @spartygw irrelevant because there is no way I can get to main in this app (this is a plug-in on other app which is not open source)

Answer (score 2):

The 3rd parameter to `main` is an array of env vars. This will dump the environment:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **env) {
    for (int i=0; env[i]!= NULL; i++) {
        std::cout << env[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled on my mac:

```
g++ -o env env.cpp
```

Run output:

```
$ ./env
NDK=/Users/spartygw/android-ndk
SSH_AGENT_PID=18108
TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/spartygw/Library/Android/sdk
TERM=xterm-256color
SHELL=/bin/bash
CLICOLOR=1
TMPDIR=/var/folders/97/hlbrfp294kdbf182909shsqw0000gn/T/
GRADLE_HOME=/Users/spartygw/bin/gradle
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=433
CVSROOT=gwarren@vpdsec.net:/home/cvs/virnetx
TERM_SESSION_ID=EC6955BE-1149-4A56-8C3E-3C86B315048E
USER=spartygw
NDKROOT=/Users/spartygw/android-ndk
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/var/folders/97/hlbrfp294kdbf182909shsqw0000gn/T//sshg8KJIbhlLFRt/agent.18106
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F5:0x0:0x0
color_prompt=yes
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/spartygw/bin/gradle/bin:/Users/spartygw/bin
PWD=/tmp
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home/
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
XPC_FLAGS=0x0
XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0
HOME=/Users/spartygw
SHLVL=2
CVS_RSH=ssh
DISPLAY=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.ZKUZySdPF2/org.macosforge.xquartz:0
```

If for some reason you don't want to capture it in `main` you can access it through the global var `environ`. Example:

```
#include <iostream>

extern char **environ;

void dump_env() {
    for(char **var = environ; *var; var++) {
        std::cout << *var << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    dump_env();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the information I actually wasn't aware of that however I was wondering about wchar_t* not char*. I can get environment variables as char* from **environ system variable. On Windows there is a separate variable **_wenviron for that purpose that doesn't exist on Mac (at least I haven't find it - maybe its me being stupid) so I was wondering what the mechanism for Mac is

Comment: Yeah, I updated my answer. You can get the `environ` array anywhere. It's always going to be a char **